# why the parameter does not passed Axios requests?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, axios

I had following code to setup urls for Axios requests. In razor page, I have this.

```
    var urls = {
         Value1Validate: '@Url.Action("Method1", "Controler1")',
         Value2Validate: '@Url.Action("Method2", "Controler2")',
     };
```

In js file, I have code as below. Anyone could help me find out why this elem.val() parameter value could not be passed to the /controller2/method2?

```
    App.Value2OnChange = (e) => {
        let elem = $(e);
        alert("parameter value " + elem.val());

        axios.get(`${urls.Value2Validate}${elem.val()}`).then((response) => {
            if (response.data === 'ok') {
                 //dispay msg ('PASSED');
            } else {
                //dispay msg ('Failed');
            }
        });
    }
```

Here are the code in Controller2.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> Method2(string parameterValue)
    {
        var response = await MediatR.Send(new ValidateionQuery(parameterValue)));
        return JsonSuccess(response ? "ok" : "error");
    }
```

I tried the code and it called .../controller2/method2 but did not pass the parameter value.  Any wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

The default [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) for simple parameter types is to retrieve them from the request query string.

To pass your value, you can use Axios' `params` option

```js
axios.get(urls.Value2Validate, {
  params: {
    parameterValue: elem.val(), // note the key name matches your action parameter
  }
});
```

You could also make this explicit in your action by using the `[FromQuery]` attribute

```c#
public async Task<JsonResult> Method2([FromQuery] string parameterValue)
{
    // ...
}
```